# Contraction of Have/Has/Had

Tags: contractions

Can I use the contraction after a proper noun? Please look at this sentence.

Anu'd been living with her parents and two elder brothers. [For Informal Context]

Answer (score 1):

We can certainly use a contraction after a proper noun. "John's gone away", for example, is fine in informal use.

*Have* and *had* are a bit more problematic, I think. We would certainly elide "Anu had been living..." in speech, but it looks odd in writing unless you are consciously reproducing very informal speech in a story or play.

Comment: "... unless you are consciously reproducing very informal speech in a story or play." I absolutely concur.